# How to add material design css in wordpress and woocommerce

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, css, javascript

I am creating theme from scratch.
I want to add material design css / forms / components and style in my theme.
Can someone please assist me how to start. 
How can I disable default wordpress and woocommerce styles and add material design styles ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to WordPress.StackExchange! I think your question is a bit too broad to be answered here properly. What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you having problems with what in particular? To answer your broad question: You can add your styles via [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and remove styles via [`wp_dequeue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/) plus [resetting styled elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903168) where you cant dequeue